# opencv Threshold Truncate works as if it is inverted

Tags: opencv, truncate, threshold

I have noticed sth strange about `cv.THRESH_TRUNC`. Normally, this function should work like this:

```
threshold : if src(x,y) > thresh

otherwise : src(x,y)
```

But in my code and in this tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

It works inverted, like this:

```
maxVal : if src(x,y) > thresh

src(x,y) : otherwise
```

Does anyone know why.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show code, input and output?

Comment: What version are you using? The [current version](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp) has `THRESH_TRUNC` defined as `return std::min(src, thresh);`.

Comment: Thank you beaker, 
I'm using 4.2.0 -
If this is the case then this documentation is not wright is it?
https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html

Comment: They seem to say the same thing to me. (If you tag someone in your reply like @beaker, they'll be notified when you respond.)